# Track down .Net6 app publish dependencies

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way to figure out what exactly brings in an assembly dependency in a .Net6 application *during a publish*?

My problem specifically is that a pure WPF application is bringing in very large WinForms dlls, not just the runtime but also the design time dlls, and I can't figure out why. Nothing seems to be referencing them in my code and I'm certain I'm not using any WinForms code, but still it's there. There isn't even any `<UseWindowsForms>` project tag to bring in the references.

Comment: Could you please post the references from the project file(s) (projects, assemblies, packages). Also, are you publishing at the solution level or at the project level?

Comment: Project level. And you misread my question, I'm asking how I can track down the dependencies myself, I'm not asking you to do it for me. If you know something, feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: In that case I can suggest to peek at the [.NET SDK 6 source code](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/tree/v6.0.300/src/Cli/dotnet/commands/dotnet-publish) and trace it back to the piece of code that resolves dependencies.

Comment: Sure, that's one solution. Anyway short of debugging .net itself, does anyone have any other idea?

Comment: A test you can try is to setup a brand new WPF app with the default settings, publish, then check whether WinForms is output. If not, add the same NuGet packages and other references from your main project and dependent projects one by one until you find the one that causes WinForms to output to the publish directory.